# Code to run when app terminates from Suspended state

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, swift

I am working on an iOS app that has Multitasking enabled.Now, I want to perform some stuff when the app quits but not when it goes to the background. I understand we have following methods:

1. applicationWillEnterBackground:
2. applicationWillEnterBackground:

These methods are always called when app goes in background not necessarily getting terminated. I don't want to run my code if its in background but not terminating.

1. applicationWillTerminate:

This method works great if I terminate my app while in foreground or background but (according to Apple documentation) this method only gets called only when the app terminates while it is in foreground or background but not in the suspended state.

So, I would like to know how can I make my code run when the app is terminated while in suspended mode as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Comment: I have a multipeer connectivity app, I want my code to tear down the session when the app is terminating but not while its in background only.